# In Prolog is it possible to have NOT operation in left hand side of a statement?

Tags: prolog

In GNU Prolog it possible to have NOT operation in left hand side of a statement while it is impossible to have OR or AND connectives in left hand side.

In pure Prolog is it possible to do the same? If not what are the alternatives?

```
%Code:

happy(X) :- rich(X).
happy(arvin).
rich(darvin).


live(X) :- happy(X).
live(carvin).
live(ervin).

criminal(ervin).
criminal(barvin).

not(happy(X)) :- criminal(X).
```

Comment: The `not` in `not(happy(X)) :- criminal(X).` is not really a "not". It is just a predicate which happens to be named `not/1`, in this case with the term `happy(X)` as argument. If you try `\+ happy(X) :- criminal(X).` you will get a complaint by the Prolog Processor.

Comment: Alternatives to go beyond Horn Clauses "A <- B & C & D" with negation-as-failure `\+` on the right-hand-side are first-order-logic theorem provers like [Vampire](http://www.vprover.org/). Also, there may be Answer Set Programming systems which accept strong negation on the right-hand side? Not sure.

Answer (score 4):

No. Prolog clauses (be they in GNU-Prolog or any other system) are Horn-Clauses only. Also negation on the right-hand side is very limited in its applicability.